# Is the domain of $\arccos (2 \sin x)$ correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have calculated the domain of  $\arccos (2 \sin x)$ and I got that it is $[-\pi/2 , \pi/2]$ .... am I correct?

Comment: Just graph the function and check for yourself.  And your answer is incorrect. Hint: $2\sin{x}$ is periodic.

Comment: No, it is not. $\sin\frac\pi2=1$ and $\arccos 2$ is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of $\mathrm{Arccos}$ is $[-1,1]$. So the domain of your function is $\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } 2 \sin(x) \in [-1,1] \rbrace$, i.e. $\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } \sin(x) \in [-1/2,1/2] \rbrace$

Now the solutions of
$$-\frac{1}{2} \leq \sin(x) \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

are all the $x \in [-\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{6}] \cup  [\frac{5\pi}{6}, \frac{7\pi}{6}] \quad (\text{modulo } 2\pi)$. So the domain of your function is exactly
$$\mathcal{D} = \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} [-\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi, \frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi] \cup  [\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi, \frac{7\pi}{6}+2k\pi]$$

Comment: How you got the second interval of the union, $[5\pi/6, 7\pi/6]$?

Comment: Just draw the unit circle, and try to see on it which are the angles whose sinus belongs to $[-1/2,1/2]$. You will see that there are two intervals of solutions on the circle.

Comment: By definition, the sinus of an angle is the $y-$coordinate of the point of the unit circle corresponding to this angle. I cannot help you more if you don't know what actually a sinus is.

Comment: Or simply: $$\mathcal{D} = \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \left[-\frac{\pi}{6}+k\pi, \frac{\pi}{6}+k\pi\right].$$

Answer (score 2):

$$0  \le \arccos (2 \sin x) \le \pi \\ \implies -1\le2\sin x\le 1\\ \implies -1/2 \le \sin x \le1/2$$ now the range of x will be domain of  $\arccos (2 \sin x)$ 
$$\text{EDIT: }$$ as these are periodic functions ,
 we talk about principal domain or principal ranges which makes sense
[principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value)